# How to get return value from MATLAB function

Tags: shell-script, function, exit-status, matlab

I am calling a MATLAB function with a bash script

```
matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -nodisplay -r "matlabfunction input1 input2; quit"
```

I am trying to get a one digit return value from the matlab function, so I can proceed to other routine base on this return value.

Comment: is the value in the `$?` return code, or is it printed to the screen, or?

Comment: Adding to Jeff's comment, `echo $?` right after you execute your script, gives you the number you want?

Comment: echo $? prints out 0 no matter what my return value is.  I am not sure if I have my syntax wrong.  All I did was  matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -nodisplay -r "matlabfunction input1 input2; quit" && echo $?

Comment: Your are not doing anything wrong, a exit value of 0 means matlab exited without any issues. You need to tell matlab to use a different exit value, but bash will think that matlab crashed if the exit value is non zero and then `&&` will not work.

Comment: If I echo $? before the quit statement, it does print out the right value.    matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -nodisplay -r "matlabfunction input1 input2" echo $?
How would I save it into a variable? 
I tried matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -nodisplay -r "matlabfunction input1 input2" status=$(echo $?) 

And how do I still execute the quit statement to get out of matlab?

Comment: Have you looked at my answer?

Comment: Yes, I have.  And I am not using && anymore.  Is there still a way to do what I want to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can quit matlab with either `quit` or `exit`. They are basically the same except with `exit` you can specify an exit code. If you are willing to abuse the exit code then you can do something like

```
matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -nodisplay -r "exit(times(2, 7));" > /dev/null; echo $?
```

If you are going to do this realize that bash may get upset about non-zero exit codes and you may need some error handling to make sure your function returns an error code that exit can handle.

The other option is to capture the output of matlab and then parse what you want

```
matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -nodisplay -r "format compact; Answer=times(2, 7), exit" | sed -ne '/Answer =/{n;p}' | sed -e 's/ *//g'
```